# Dynamically adding views in grid layout doesn't take the size specified

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I am creating an app in which I want to dynamically add items to grid layout and want them to look like this:

[image]

What I did to achieve this is given as follows:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/myGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </GridLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**item_layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:background="@color/itemBackground"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="ORAL CARE"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:** (Code adding items in grid layout)

```
gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
        myArray = new String[]{"pink","blue","red","orange","green","purple","white","black","brown","other"};
        int total = myArray.length;
        int column =  2;
        int row = total / column;
        gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(row + 1);
        LinearLayout linearLayoutItem;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int displayWidth = display.getWidth();
        int displayHeight = display.getHeight();
        for(int i =0, c = 0, r = 0; i < total; i++, c++)
        {
            if(c == column)
            {
                c = 0;
                r++;
            }
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, gridLayout, false);
            TextView cText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cText);
            ImageView cImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cImage);
            cText.setText(myArray[i]);
            cImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);


            v.setMinimumWidth(displayWidth/2); // setting width and height
            v.setMinimumHeight(displayWidth/2);
            gridLayout.addView(v);

            GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            param.rightMargin = 20;
            param.topMargin = 20;
            param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c);
            param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(r);
```

This code is adding the views in grid layout perfectly. But the problem is that it is not adjusting the size of view according to the screen, as shown:

[image]

I have tried to make the view's width equal to half the space of screen but it doesn't seem to work. The image which I am using in imageView is large but I have tried experimenting with the size of the imageView as well but it doesn't work.

What I want is to:

1. Adjust the views (the gray colored views with image and text) according to the size of the screen on which it is run. As width of grid layout is match_parent.
2. Height of the view to be in ratio with width of the view.
3. Size of the image in the view to be in ratio with the size of the view.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't use RecyclerView+GridLayoutManager or at least GridView? Right in this views you don't need to take a care about calculating dimensions.

Comment: implement by `RecyclerView` for easy and flexibility

Comment: @jantursky
Thankyou.. I didn't know that I can use recycler view grid layout manager :)